# Why won't this work? Running command + variable

Tags: powershell

This won't work:

```
$server = "server";
$cmd = "hostname";
C:\Users\ss\Documents\Scripts\PSTools\PsExec.exe \\$server $cmd;
```

But this will:

```
$server = "server";
C:\Users\ss\Documents\Scripts\PSTools\PsExec.exe \\$server hostname;
```

Why?

Comment: The first one worked for me. What error did you get...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try appending a & to the front of the command:

& C:\Users\ss\Documents\Scripts\PSTools\PsExec.exe \$server $cmd;